# Alterar nome dos objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
{
    "Search Engines": [
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 5,
            "bytes": 50189
        },
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 7601
        },
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 6,
            "bytes": 613036
        },
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 2858
        }
    ],
    "Content Server": [
        {
            "conta": "Content Server",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 17308
        },
        {
            "conta": "Content Server",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 47412
        },
        {
            "conta": "Content Server",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 24210
        }
    ],
    "Business": [
        {
            "conta": "Business",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 2847
        }
    ],
    "Internet Services": [
        {
            "conta": "Internet Services",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 3690
        }
    ]
}
```

Como eu posso trocar o nome de todos os objetos ("Search engines", "Content Server", "Business", "Internet"...) para "teste"? Preciso que eles tenham nomes iguais

Comment: Isso parece um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode ter todos eles com o mesmo nome. Pode fazer "teste1", "teste2", "teste3", e por ai vai, mas chamar todas as propriedades de um objeto com o mesmo nome vai te causar sérios problemas.
Dito isso, para mudar o nome da propriedade, apenas crie uma nova com o nome que deseja, e então apague a antiga. Exemplo:

```
objeto.teste3 = objeto.Business;
delete objeto.Business;
console.log(objeto.teste3);
```

Lembrando que neste exemplo, "objeto" é o nome do objeto em questão (não foi colocado na descrição da pergunta)

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Leticia, tudo bem?

Fiquei na dúvida se você queria alterar os nomes que foram adicionados às propriedades `conta` ou se queria alterar o nome das coleções de objetos.

Se você quiser alterar o nome das coleções, elas não poderão mais ficar dentro do mesmo objeto, uma vez que o nome estaria duplicado para todas as propriedades. Uma alternativa seria criar um novo objeto, definir uma nova coleção com nome personalizado e fazer uma lista com os objetos que você tem. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
{
    "nome_personalizado": [
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 5,
            "bytes": 50189
        },
        {
            "conta": "Search Engines",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 7601
        },
        ...
        ,
        {
            "conta": "Content Server",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 17308
        },
        ...
        ,
        {
            "conta": "Internet Services",
            "hits": 1,
            "bytes": 3690
        }
    ]
}
```

Por outro lado, se quiser padronizar o atributo `conta` dos diferentes objetos das coleções, então acredito que um simples `foreach` modificando este atributo iria resolver seu problema.

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços.